# Declare global variables in a loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, variables, global

Is it possible to declare global variables in MATLAB inside a loop:

```
cellvar = { 'ni' ; 'equity' ; 'assets' } ;
for i = 1:size(cellvar,1)
    global cellvar{1}  % --> THIS GIVES AN ERROR
end

% Desired result:
global ni
global equity
global assets
```

Matlab documentation says: "There is no function form of the global command (i.e., you cannot use parentheses and quote the variable names)."  Any suggested work-around?  Thanks!

Comment: **Don't do it!**  Global variables and use of `eval` are both best avoided.

Comment: nibot has a point. I imagine there are probably better ways to do whatever it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [EVAL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/eval.html) function to do this:

```
for var = 1:numel(cellvar)
  eval(['global ' cellvar{var}]);
end
```

Also, since [GLOBAL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/global.html) accepts a command-line list of variable names, you could avoid the for loop by using [SPRINTF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sprintf.html) to concatenate your variable names into one string to be evaluated:

```
 eval(['global' sprintf(' %s',cellvar{:})]);
```